# searching in database (mongoDB) with millions of records takes more than 1 minute to retrieve data

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I'm using node js and while searching for a field it takes over 1 minute or more to get the data back is there any solutions to increase performance and make it faster

here is my code:

```
router.get('/employee', (req,res) => {
    let searchQuery = {name: req.query.name};

    Employee.findOne(searchQuery)
        .then(employee => {
            res.render('search',{employee:employee});
            
        })
        .catch(err => {
            req.flash('error_msg', 'ERROR: '+err)
            res.redirect('/');
        })
});
```

Schema:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

let employeeScheme = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    postion: String,
    salary: String
});
module.exports = mongoose.model('Employee', employeeScheme);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeap. You can create an index for fields you normally search for.

Exemple:

```
employeeScheme.index({ name: 1, type: 1 })
```

Read the documentation for choose the best index type for you.
https://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#indexes